# Simple example for mean, variance and sd - but getting different results in R

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, variance, standard-deviation

Trying to use R/Rstudio (latest version),
to calculate the: 
 - Mean, 
 - Variance and 
 - Std Deviation
in this specific, simple problem:

http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html

...but my R results
are different from the example page, above.

This is what I did in R:

```
>  dogs 
[1] 600 470 170 430 300
>  str(dogs) 
 num [1:5] 600 470 170 430 300
>  mean(dogs) 
[1] 394      ## page result: mean = 394, ok!
>  var(dogs) 
[1] 27130    ## page result:  var = 21,704 ?
>  sd(dogs) 
[1] 164.7119 ## page result:   sd = 147 ?
>
```

Q1:  Am I using the wrong R functions?
 Q2:  Are there any other R functions/packages
which would yield the correct answer, *easily and directly*?
(the "summary" and the "summarize" function in **dplyr** pkg. 
 don't give these results either...).

Thanks for any pointers...

UPDATE:-----------------
I finally figured it out:
- R uses the SAMPLE var and sd functions
- the example page uses the POPULATION var and sd functions
  (which are not "natively" available in R).

Thus the difference in results...

Which leaves me hanging 
w/these 2 relevant Questions:

Q1 - Why are the POPULATION sd() and var() functions
     not "natively" available in R?
     (instead of having each user define the functions manually)
and

Q2 - Is there an R-package in CRAN which includes 
     a super-set of Descriptive Statistics functions,
     not "natively" available in R?

Thanks for any pointers, ideas etc...

Comment: Because _no one_ uses population sd and var functions in real life.

Comment: Thank you, Hadley. I'm learning Rstudio and Statistics but I DO see your point and it makes sense. I wonder why the author of the dogs example used POPULATION sd() and var()...  Q: Are there no "real life" situations where the population sd/var would make sense at all?